# Addon: run execute() only when button is clicked

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'd like to create an addon, which has some properties and a button. The addon should only does the scene modification when the button is clicked.

Currently my addon is placed into the specials menu of the curve. When I select it, its properties are displayed on the side panel and its execute() method is executed immediately.

I'd like to have a button under the properties on the side panel and to do the scene modification only when the button is clicked.

Where can I find an example for this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also add an invoke method and call [WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=types.wind#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog):

```
def invoke(self, context, event):
    return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution currently, because it was easy to adapt :) Ok it is not on the side panel but on a dialog, but it seems to be good for my case.

Comment: There is an issue with this. When I press OK on the dialog, the operator and its properties are also displayed on the side panel. Is it possible to deny it?

Comment: Don't use the `REGISTER` option in `bl_options` of your operator. See [docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=types.operat#bpy.types.Operator.bl_options)